# Removing noise selectively from DEM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, contour, srtm, noise

I am looking for a processing tool that can remove noise selectively from a DEM (Mostly SRTM). My current workflow includes "Fill sinks" and "r.neighbours". The problem is that the tool is blind to places of abrupt slope changes and smooths the surface uniformly. I would like to apply a different amount of smoothing to areas of different slope values.

How can I do that?

[image: Please see the attached image]

Comment: Did you try a lowpass filter?